# Missing URI template variable with matching variable names

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Hi I am getting the following Error for the following Method whenever I try accessing it with Postman

```
2021-03-08 11:40:06.325  WARN 18676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'commentID' for method parameter of type String]

{
"timestamp": "2021-03-08T11:28:07.651+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Missing URI template variable 'commentID' for method parameter of type String",
"path": "/vssp/comments/2"
}
```

I believe this Method to be correct and I have others like this that work.

```
@DeleteMapping("/vssp/comments/{​​​​​​​​​​​​​​commentID}")
public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<Comment>> deleteComment(@PathVariable String commentID, @RequestHeader("Password") String password) {
    logger.info("DELETE -> COMMENT[AUBI|" + commentID + "]");
    if(DatabaseController.checkPassword(password)) {
        DatabaseController.deleteComment(Integer.parseInt(commentID), password);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Is there an error stack trace in your application log? The error could be caused by some other code that is called by the `deleteComment` method.

Comment: the checkPassword method is used on many other occasions and i added e.printStacktrace to the deleteComment one but i don't get any other errors